# How does this check work with operator precedence in JS

Tags: javascript, operators

So I'm reading through this precedence table https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

It says 20 - 1 with 20 being highest precedence.

`16 Logical NOT right-to-left   ! …` So the `!` operator has a precedence of 16.

`10 Strict Equality … === …` So the `===` operator has a precendence of 10.

This lines

```
!'hello' === 'goodbye'
```

How does this get executed/read? By reading it I thought. In steps it goes;

*'hello' === 'goodbye'* Check then, *invert bool value*. So If it returns true set it to false.

If i'm reading through the precedence operators table. It looks to me like it does the `!` operator first and then `===`.

How does it invert a non-bool value beforehand and then do the truthy check? Like how does it work could someone explain?

Thank you!

Comment: `By reading it I thought. In steps it goes; 'hello' === 'goodbye' Check then, invert bool value. So If it returns true set it to false.` why would you think it does that? `!` has a higher operator precedence than equality - you said so yourself. Therefore, logically it would *first* try to "invert" `"hello"` and *then* compare it with `"goodbye"`.

Comment: @vlaz yup but I wasn't aware of operator precedence before reading that MDN table. So I thought it worked `===` compare the values than `! returned bool value` but I was wrong. Then I was curious how it actually works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks to me like it does the ! operator first and then ===.

Yes. 16 is a higher number than 10, so `!` has a higher precedence than `===`, so it is resolved first.

> How does it invert a non-bool value beforehand and then do the truthy check?

See [the spec for !](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-logical-not-operator) which points to [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean) which says:

> String:   Return false if argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise return true.

Comment: So what it actually looks like is `true === 'goodbye'`? `!` calls `ToBoolean` on the string `'hello'` and then runs the `===` operator?

Comment: @TryingToLearnJS — No, because ! will turn `true` to `false`

Comment: It will convert the string to a boolean *and then invert it*. A non-empty string is coerced to a boolean `true`, then inverted to `false`, then compared with a different string.

Comment: Ah I see thank you! That makes sense. Sorry for a stupid question :D I appreciate the help